# tshark decryption fails on old OS but succeeds on new OS

Tags: openssl, decryption

I have a pcap tracefile and private RSA key that should allow me to decrypt the HTTPS data in the pcap file.

With the exact same pcap file, private key and tshark command, I find that decryption fails in Oracle Linux 6 but succeeds in Ubuntu 18 and RHEL 8.

I would like to know what difference in environment/versions allows decryption to succeed on newer OSs but fail on the older OS.

**tshark command** is as follows (IP, private key path and pcap name simplified here):

```
tshark -V -n -o ssl.keys_list:1.2.3.4,443,http,/path/to/key.pem -o ssl.desegment_ssl_records:TRUE -o ssl.desegment_ssl_application_data:TRUE -o ssl.debug_file:rsa_private.log -r ./trace.pcap
```

**Client Hello** TLS information (as seen on RHEL8):

```
TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
Extension: server_name (len=24)
Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
Extension: signature_algorithms (len=20)
Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
Extension: supported_groups (len=8)
```

**Server Hello** TLS information (as seen on RHEL8):

```
Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
Extension: server_name (len=0)
Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
```

In my `rsa_private.log` log I find the following error messages on the old OS:

```
ssl_decrypt_record found padding 111 final len -48
ssl_decrypt_record wrong record len/padding outlen 96
ssl_decrypt_record: mac failed
```

Version information from different environments:

**Oracle Linux 6** (fails to decrypt):

- TShark 1.8.10
- GLib 2.28.8
- GnuTLS 2.12.23
- Gcrypt 1.4.5
- Linux 4.1.12-124.30.1.el6uek.x86_64
- libpcap version 1.4.0

**Ubuntu 18** (decrypts successfully):

- TShark (Wireshark) 2.6.10
- GLib 2.56.4
- GnuTLS 3.5.18
- Gcrypt 1.8.1
- Linux 4.18.0-22-generic
- libpcap version 1.8.1

**RHEL8** (decrypts successfully):

- TShark (Wireshark) 2.6.2
- GLib 2.56.1
- GnuTLS 3.6.4
- Gcrypt 1.8.3
- Linux 4.18.0-80.4.2.el8_0.x86_64
- libpcap version 1.9.0-PRE-GIT

I presume something was added to libcrypt/openssl/gcrypt that allows the newer OS's to decrypt my traffic successfully, but I wonder what?

I have found other traffic using the same TLS version and cipher suite decrypt fine in the older OS.

**EDIT:** adding detail about TLS extension visibility in OL6 vs RHEL8:

OL6 shows the extension as follows (in both Hello's):

```
Extension: Extended Master Secret        
    Type: Extended Master Secret (0x0017)
    Length: 0
```

RHEL8 shows the extension as follows (in both Hello's):

```
Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
    Type: extended_master_secret (23)
    Length: 0
```

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - Our site is really more about the mathematical details of cryptography than tasks such as this. This question is more suitable for a site like superuser - allow me to migrate this there for you.

Comment: **Almost certainly it's extended_master_secret** rfc7627 published in 2015-09, which changes the key derivation and thus the keys. Wireshark 1.8.10 was in 2013-09, 2.6.2 in 2018-07 and 2.6.10 just a few months ago in 2019-07. Does OL6/1.8.10 even show the hello extension decoded as EMS? (The crypto library versions won't have made any difference; RSA HMAC-SHA1 and AES-128-CBC haven't changed since about 2001.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight - it would explain the failure to decrypt on OL6. I have added details about EMS appearance in OL6 vs RHEL8.

 I am developing a C application that uses OpenSSL 1.0.x to perform TLS decryption. My app is failing similar to tshark in OL6. Do you know if newer extensions like EMS require OpenSSL 1.1.x to read correctly, or can I get by with OpenSSL 1.0.x?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943850/send-openssl-client-hello-with-extended-master-secret-disabled implies 1.0.x will not allow modern extensions to be read.